# Why is my 'select into a variable' statement making my stored procedure not insert anything into the table?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

So I currently have a stored procedure that does a simple insert into a table called 'VALUE'. I tested this piece and called the procedure below:

```
Create Or Replace Procedure TEST_PROCEDURE(rValue_tx IN VARCHAR, rData_Type IN VARCHAR)
IS
BEGIN
IF rValue_Tx >= 0 THEN
                IF rData_Type in ('TEST', 'REAL')
                THEN
                Insert into Value (VALUE_ID, VALUE_TX, CREATE_DT)
                VALUES (1, rValue_tx, SYSDATE);
END IF;
END IF;
END TEST_PROCEDURE;
```

However; when i try to insert a number into a variable (adding another layer of complexity), nothing gets inserted. Below is code with another layer of complexity added to it:

```
Create Or Replace Procedure TEST_PROCEDURE_NEW(rValue_tx IN VARCHAR, rData_Type IN VARCHAR)
IS
v_MAX_historic_value value.value_tx%type;
BEGIN
---
SELECT MAX(BUFFER_MAX)
  INTO v_MAX_Historic_Value
  FROM max_look_up;
EXCEPTION
     WHEN no_data_found
     THEN SELECT 0
            INTO v_MAX_Historic_Value
            FROM DUAL;
---
IF rValue_Tx >= 0 
THEN
                IF rData_Type in ('TEST', 'REAL')
                THEN
                Insert into Value (VALUE_ID, VALUE_TX, CREATE_DT)
                VALUES (null, rValue_tx, SYSDATE);
END IF;
END IF;
END TEST_PROCEDURE_NEW;
```

I am sure I am missing some fundamental rule of PL/SQL but can't seem to figure out which rule. It seems that it's the EXCEPTION that is causing the procedure not to insert any rows into the VALUE table, but I am not exactly sure why (or is there a better way to do this?)... any help would be greatly appreciated :(

Instead of using an EXCEPTION; is there a better way for me to handle when there is no data in max_look_up and nothing/null gets returned as a result?

Comment: Thanks John.  There are some `--- ---` in the post.  Is this the entire procedure?  If not, could you post the full procedure?  From what is here, it looks like the Insert would only be available if a `no_data_found` exception had been triggered (the insert is in the exception block).  The full procedure would help to verify sort that out.  Thanks

Comment: Aggregate expressions always return something, so you'll never get a `no_data_found` exception from a `select max()`.

Comment: Your first code snippet will not compile.  Nor, I'm sure, will your second example.  You aren't showing EXCEPTION in either snippet.  So there is no way you got as far as having to ponder why it doesn't work RIGHT.

Comment: @Stilgar thanks for your insightful feedback, i simplified a lot of my code so that I can dig down into what the root cause of the issue was and (in the process) deleted a few things I wasn't supposed to. i've made the appropriate edits.

Comment: Also it's `create or replace procedure`, not `create stored procedure`. And I would recommend picking an indent size and sticking with it ;)

Comment: @alexgibbs thanks. i have those in place so that my code would be easier to read. I had the code simplified slightly so that I can satisfy the forum rules (or least that's what i thought i read). do you know how I can get the insert to work and only have that exception trigger off if a null (or blank) was passed in for that particular variable?

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak no, i am filtering out values that are higher than the max

Comment: @WilliamRobertson i think nothing will be returned if there are no values at all in the table.

Comment: @JohnWick you might think that, but it's not how it works. Consider `count(*)`, which returns `0` for an empty table. All of the aggregate functions (have to) work the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only misplaced **Exception** keyword, try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_PROCEDURE_NEW (
                                                RVALUE_TX    IN VARCHAR,
                                                RDATA_TYPE   IN VARCHAR
                                               )
IS
   V_MAX_HISTORIC_VALUE   VALUE.VALUE_TX%TYPE;
BEGIN
   ---
   BEGIN
      SELECT MAX (BUFFER_MAX) INTO V_MAX_HISTORIC_VALUE FROM MAX_LOOK_UP;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
      THEN
         SELECT 0 INTO V_MAX_HISTORIC_VALUE FROM DUAL;
   END;

   ---
   IF RVALUE_TX >= 0
   THEN
      IF RDATA_TYPE IN ('TEST', 'REAL')
      THEN
         INSERT INTO VALUE (VALUE_ID, VALUE_TX, CREATE_DT)
         VALUES (NULL, RVALUE_TX, SYSDATE);
      END IF;
   END IF;
END TEST_PROCEDURE_NEW;
```

Answer (score 2):

With some proper code indenting it is obvious that all code except for the first SELECT statement is in the exception handler.

However, `SELECT MAX(...)` will always return data and never trigger the `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception. Therefore, the `INSERT` statement is never reached.

```
Create Or Replace Procedure TEST_PROCEDURE_NEW(rValue_tx IN VARCHAR, rData_Type IN VARCHAR)
IS
    v_MAX_historic_value value.value_tx%type;
BEGIN

    SELECT MAX(BUFFER_MAX)
        INTO v_MAX_Historic_Value
        FROM max_look_up;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found
    THEN
        SELECT 0
            INTO v_MAX_Historic_Value
            FROM DUAL;

        IF rValue_Tx >= 0 THEN
            IF rData_Type in ('TEST', 'REAL') THEN
                Insert into Value (VALUE_ID, VALUE_TX, CREATE_DT)
                    VALUES (null, rValue_tx, SYSDATE);
            END IF;
        END IF;
END TEST_PROCEDURE_NEW;
```

What you probably want is to move the code out of the exception handler. You would do this by introducing another pair of `BEGIN` / `END` around the first `SELECT` statement and the exception handling code. However, since the exception is never triggered, it's easier to remove the exception handling altogether. Instead, you should check for `NULL` as `MAX(...)` returns `NULL` if no rows are selected.

```
Create Or Replace Procedure TEST_PROCEDURE_NEW(rValue_tx IN VARCHAR, rData_Type IN VARCHAR)
IS
    v_MAX_historic_value value.value_tx%type;
BEGIN

    SELECT MAX(BUFFER_MAX)
        INTO v_MAX_Historic_Value
        FROM max_look_up;

    IF v_MAX_Historic_Value IS NULL THEN
        v_MAX_Historic_Value := 0;
    END IF;

    ...


    IF rValue_Tx >= 0 THEN
        IF rData_Type in ('TEST', 'REAL') THEN
            Insert into Value (VALUE_ID, VALUE_TX, CREATE_DT)
                VALUES (null, rValue_tx, SYSDATE);
        END IF;
    END IF;
END TEST_PROCEDURE_NEW;
```

Comment: extremely helpful; thanks a bunch! i'd give you bounty if i could! yeah the indents (especially with code being migrated by different tools) gets hard to keep track of. do you have any advice ? I also provided an alternate workaround that may work

Comment: also i'm a bit confused, i thought that the exception only fires off if nothing is passed in? how come nothing is inserted into the table even if i put in a value of '7' (for example) into my procedure call?

Comment: The `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception is fired if the `SELECT` statement returns no rows. That's not the case with the `MAX` expression. It will always return exactly one row.

Comment: oh... nono i  meant from my original example; would you happen to know the exact reason behind nothing being inserted into my VALUE table?

Comment: Which one is your *original example*?

Comment: @JohnWick *the indents (especially with code being migrated by different tools) gets hard to keep track of. do you have any advice ?* Yes, lay out your code neatly.

Comment: the 2nd block of code in the original question @Codo

Comment: @WilliamRobertson are there any best practices on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

After some further research I found an alternate solution (without the use of exceptions) to my question (please correct me if I'm wrong):

```
Create Or Replace Procedure TEST_PROCEDURE_NEW(rValue_tx IN VARCHAR, rData_Type IN VARCHAR)
IS
v_MAX_historic_value value.value_tx%type;
BEGIN

with EXEC as
(select 0 buffer_max
   from dual
  UNION
 select MAX(BUFFER_MAX)
    FROM max_look_up) select max(buffer_max) into v_MAX_Historic_Value from EXEC;
IF rValue_Tx >= 0 THEN
    IF rData_Type in ('TEST', 'REAL') THEN
        Insert into Value (VALUE_ID, VALUE_TX, CREATE_DT)
            VALUES (null, rValue_tx, SYSDATE);
        END IF;
    END IF;
END TEST_PROCEDURE_NEW;
```